# address finder using post codes in magento1.6

Tags: magento, street-address, zipcode

After searching the web and seeing that the PAF file is not free I'm guessing there is no way to do this.. but.. does anyone know of a free system that can find a list of address with a postcode. It just seems odd to me that google can show all address wherever you click on a map. It knows the bounds of a postcode area, but there seems to be no way of listing all those address.

I need a free solution. I'm aware of postcode anywhere and that their sales people are very active within stackoverflow, but I cannot afford to pay their prices on this project.

This project only requires UK and india postcodes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a list/database of all mailable addresses within a certain postcode?  Is that right?  That will be difficult to find, at least for free.  I know you don't need US data, but for reference, the US Postal Service is not allowed to give out this type of information, even for a fee, due to privacy concerns.  I assume that other countries have similar policies.

I work for a US-based address verification service called SmartyStreets so I have some experience with this.  There are third party services, you mentioned one, that have aggregated their own lists from various sources and can generate "saturation" mailing lists for specific postal codes.  However, due to the cost involved in generating and maintaining these lists, I doubt that you will find this type of list for free.